# How to read variables from file in Android Java

Tags: java, android, file, variables, store

I'm making a mod for an Android game where the user needs to be able to save their location, their coordinates. I've found how to make the file and save the variables within it, but don't know how to read the data from the file, waypoints.txt, when the game is launched.

```
function SaveW(){
try{
    var path=android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/games/com.mojang/";
    java.io.File(path).mkdirs();
    var newFile=new java.io.File(path,"waypoints.txt");
    newFile.createNewFile();
    var outWrite=new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(new java.io.FileOutputStream(newFile));
    if(waypoint1State == true){outWrite.append("\n" + "Waypoint1@"+waypointNameAdd1+"@"+w1x+"@"+w1y+"@"+w1z);}
    if(waypoint2State == true){outWrite.append("\n" + "Waypoint2@"+waypointNameAdd2+"@"+w2x+"@"+w2y+"@"+w2z);}
    if(waypoint3State == true){outWrite.append("\n" + "Waypoint3@"+waypointNameAdd3+"@"+w3x+"@"+w3y+"@"+w3z);}
    outWrite.close();
    }
catch(err){
    clientMessage(err);
    }
}
```

I understand my code is messy and inefficient, but that's besides the point; I'm teaching myself programming.

I'd use this to start:

```
function LoadW(){   var path=android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/games/com.mojang/";
if(java.io.File(path+"waypoints.txt").exists()){}};
```

Comment: `var path=....` - what language is this?

Comment: Probly kotlin. Use `final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);`  This question will be marked duplicated...eventually. Check this site https://www.dev2qa.com/android-read-write-external-storage-file-example/ and the Android API documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

Comment: You should use SharedPreferences, easier for beginners and many tutorials out there.